# Python paths not being set on embedded installation

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, openembedded, linux-distro

I am trying to get python3 running on my EspressoBin single board computer (aarch64). I have built a linux distribution using Marvell's [openembedded](https://github.com/MarvellEmbeddedProcessors/marvell-embedded-linux-platform) distribution and included `python3`.

The problem is that python's search paths/environment variables are not being set.

If I try to start python3, I get:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000007faef06000 (most recent call first):
Aborted
```

If, however, I do:

```
$ export PYTHONHOME="/usr/lib64/python3.5/"
$ export PYTHONPATH="/usr/lib64/python3.5/:/usr/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload"
$ python3
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jan 14 2019, 23:24:54) 
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Then everything magically works.

So the question is... where/how are these things normally being set? I tried comparing to Ubuntu, but for some reason those environment variables aren't even present at all! I checked the docs on [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) and it says that `sys.path` is populated from PYTHONPATH, "plus an installation-dependent default". So I'm guessing Ubuntu's "installation-dependent default" has the correct paths pre-populated?

My current solution is to just add those two environment variables to `/etc/environment`, as well as `/etc/profile` (for ssh connections), but this seems like a hacky workaround and I want to do it right.

Comment: Are you using a window OS?

Comment: No, Xubuntu 18.04 to build, deployed to EspressoBin (running marvell-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path `".../lib64/..."` to python3.5 does not look default,

> "By default, the libraries are searched in `prefix/lib/pythonversion`
>   and `exec_prefix/lib/pythonversion` " [source](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)

So I guess that it could be related to that and if you could reinstall or modify it to be installed in `"/lib/"` instead of `"/lib64/"` you wouldn't need to set those two environment variables.

Comment: Indeed, adding a softlink `/usr/lib/python3.5 -> /usr/lib64/python3.5` seems to fix the issue (I'm able to eliminate the environment variables). `lib64` must be some installation prefix openembedded is choosing because of the architecture `aarch64`... I'll have to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed that my `${libdir}` is being change from the default `lib` to `lib64` because of the architecture `aarch64`

Comment: Solution is to either modify the python recipe, modify local.conf, or add softlink in a `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Modules/getpath.c in Python source tree would not be a bad idea.

Oh, and: there seems to be a version mismatch? Python is 3.6, yet you provide 3.5 modules to it?